# Batch file to loop through a directory and create a variable based on each file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with a list of server IP addresses and the code below (which I've scrapped together from other coding) loops through it and brings back a modified date of a named file for each server in the list...

```
@ECHO On
SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%a IN (C:\Scripts\Servers.txt) DO (
 CALL :getmod %%a
)

GOTO :EOF

:getmod
SET Server=%1
SET File=Abs_Client.exe

FOR %%i IN ("\\%Server%\C$\Com_Dir\%File%") DO SET modif_time=%%~ti
Echo %Server% %File% %modif_time% >> "C:\Scripts\Server_App_Mod_date.txt"

GOTO :eof
```

That works great...however, what I'd like to do is create another loop around it which creates a variable for each file in a directory and pass that into the code above instead of having to manually change the 'SET File' as shown above for individual files.

Something along the lines of;

```
@ECHO On
SETLOCAL

FOR /D %VAR IN ("\\Network_Location\AppMedia\App Source Files\Prod Apps\Server_Update") DO (

FOR /f %%a IN (C:\Scripts\Servers.txt) DO (
 CALL :getmod %%a
)

GOTO :EOF

:getmod
SET Server=%1
SET File=%VAR

FOR %%i IN ("\\%Server%\C$\Com_Dir\%File%") DO SET modif_time=%%~ti
Echo %Server% %File% %modif_time% >> "C:\Scripts\Server_App_Mod_date.txt"

GOTO :eof

)
```

Clearly it's wrong so any ideas/help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't testet, but maybe a hint in the right direction:

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL 

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR "\\Network_Location\AppMedia\App Source Files\Prod Apps\Server_Update" /s /b /a:-d') DO (
  FOR /F %%A IN (C:\Scripts\Servers.txt) DO (
    CALL :getmod %%A "%%~nxF"
  )
)

GOTO :EOF

:getmod
SET Server=%1
SET "tmpFile=%~2"

FOR %%I IN ("\\%Server%\C$\Com_Dir\%tmpFile%") DO ECHO %Server% %tmpFile% %%~tI >> "C:\Scripts\Server_App_Mod_date.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

As far as i know, FOR /D only executes for directorys and if i understand your question, you have files in "Prod Apps\Server_Update", for each you like to have the file-date/time from the target-server... right?

Edit:

Maybe this works too:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR "\\Network_Location\AppMedia\App Source Files\Prod Apps\Server_Update" /s /b /a:-d') DO (
  FOR /F %%A IN (C:\Scripts\Servers.txt) DO (
    FOR %%X IN ("\\%%A\C$\Com_Dir\%%~nxF") DO ECHO %%A %%~nxF %%~tX >> "C:\Scripts\Server_App_Mod_date.txt"
  )
)
```

without the :getmod

Edit: /b-switch was missing from the first DIR-Command in 2nd suggestion

Comment: Excellent :) The first one works perfectly, thanks very much :) the second just repeats "AppMedia is AppMedia" in the resulting text file?

Comment: aah... there is the /b-switch missing in the first DIR-Command... dunno if it's all... have not tried, only hardcoded. :) 

i'll correct the script, please have a try :) I'm not that familiar with those file-operation-for-loops. (to get timestamps for example)

Or maybe the 3rd for-loop must not have quotes... :/

Comment: Nice one! :) That also works a treat now too, seems to run quicker too :) Thanks again.

Comment: Oops, one last thing - I noticed it runs on any file in any sub directories within the source directory 'Server_Update'...how do I avoid that?

Comment: delete the /s in the first for-loop. that's for subdirectorys. 
Maybe that now the "%%~nxF" has to be changed.

Or if you have always the same fileextension just change "Prod Apps\Server_Update" to "Prod Apps\Server_Update\\*.fileextension" - this will also circle through subdirectorys and proceed if a file with the given fileextension was found.

Comment: Could I also use '\Server_Update\*.*'?

Comment: Testet. If you just delete the /s-subdirectory-param "%%~nxF" works as expected and still "delivers" "filename.extension" (w/o quotes). :)

Comment: The "\" in the comment above wasn't shown. Had to type "\\" so that one "\" is visible... :/ 

"\Server_Update\*.*" will be the same result as "\Server_Update". as long as you use the /b /a:-d switches.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO On
SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%a IN (C:\Scripts\Servers.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b/a-d "\\%%a\C$\Com_Dir\*"') DO Echo %%a %%i %%~ti >> "C:\Scripts\Server_App_Mod_date.txt"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Should work, IIUC. Can't test, I'm afraid...

[Edit - removed call to `getmod` - not required]

Comment: Thanks for the help...can't get it to work, I'm not sure where to put the source directory in to read from? My 'Code-Fu' is clearly weak...